# How to calculate an equilibrium constant from concentrations and a reaction equation

Tags: equilibrium, concentration

2.50 mL of 0.0150 M A, 3.50 mL of 0.0250 M B, and 4.00 mL of distilled water were added to a 50-mL beaker. At equilibrium the concentration of C is 2.05*10^-3M at 25degrees celsius. Calculate Kc for the following reaction.

\[\ce{2A + B <=> 3C}\]

Comment: This is a [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-‎homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) question. We have a policy which states that ‎you should show your thoughts and/or efforts into solving the problem. It'll make us certain that ‎we aren't doing your homework for you. Otherwise, this question may get closed.‎

Comment: Sorry im new to this website. How would i go about answering this though im confused.

Comment: Do you know the answer, or you have no clues about what to do?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! If you want to get familiar with the site, please take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) which explains a lot.

Comment: I took the liberty to remove the confusion from the title of your question and maybe my answer gives some directions too. In the end, the work is yours - but so is the success ;)

Answer (score 1):

1. Start with the equation for the equilibrium constant

For a reaction $\ce{a\cdot A + b\cdot B <=> c\cdot C}$, the equilibrium constant $K_c$ is given as

\[K_c = \mathrm{\frac{[C]^c}{[A]^a\cdot[B]^b}}\]

2. Get familiar with the concept of **ICE** charts.

   - Determine the concentrations of **A** and **B** for the moment when you have poured together the solutions of **A** and **B** and diluted the mixture with water. (Don't forget about the water!)
   - Imagine that you've worked incredibly fast and no reaction has taken place! *This is the **I**nitial situation*.
   - Now have a look at the reaction equation to figure out what happens when **A** and **B** react to yield **C**. Denote the change of the concentration of **C** as $x$ (or $3x$) if you think that is easier to handle. How does the formation of $x$ moles of **C** change the concentration of **A** and **B**? *This the **C**hange part*.
   - Can you use the information from the **I**nitial and the **C**hange part to express the concentration of the reactants in the **E**quilibrium, knowing that $[\ce{C}]$ is $2.05\cdot 10^{-3} \mathrm{mol\cdot L^{-1}}$?
     *(Yes, that's the **E** part of the **ICE**)*.
3. Feed these concentrations, actually "some expressions with $x$" in the equation for $K_c$ and solve.
4. Success ;)